# Display empty_label on required selectDateWidget on Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

According to Django's Doc on SelectDateWidget (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget), the `empty_label` will be shown if the `DateField` is not required. I noticed if the `DateField` is required, the default value on the widget will be `January`, `1`, and `<current-year>`. Is there a way to make the `DateField` required, but showing the widget with `empty_label` (such as -----) on the initial form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, empty label in `SelectDateWidget` is only used if field is not required, but you can simply change this by subclassing `SelectDateWidget` and overriding `create_select` method:

```
class MySelectDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):

    def create_select(self, *args, **kwargs):
        old_state = self.is_required
        self.is_required = False
        result = super(MySelectDateWidget, self).create_select(*args, **kwargs)
        self.is_required = old_state
        return result
```

But in that case you may have to override also validation of your field, so it will throw error that field is required, not that choice is invalid when select is left on blank value.

Comment: Superb. The error thrown when all 3 fields were blank was "This field is required", and when 1 or more fields were blank was "Enter a valid date". I think that's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I assumed that validation is not prepared for it, but looks like, it is.

Comment: In django 1.11 (maybe in earlier versions as well) this will not work anymore. The SelectDateWidget seems to have been rewritten. create_select function is no longer used.

Answer (score 3):

Although `create_select` has been removed in recent versions of Django I was able to use an approach very similar to @GwynBleidD's answer by subclassing SelectDateWidget and overriding get_context.

```
class MySelectDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        old_state = self.is_required
        self.is_required = False
        context = super(MySelectDateWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        self.is_required = old_state
        return context
```

Comment: I can confirm this works in django 1.11. If you add this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091004/empty-choice-with-selectdatewidget-in-django-1-11, I'll accept it. If it is accepted here as correct answer, I'll link my question to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of SelectDateWidget there is no nice way to do this(django 2.1.4).
My solution was to add the empty choices client-side(using jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select-widget-id select').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).children('[value=""], [selected]').length) {
      $(this).prepend('<option value="" selected="selected">---</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to set your form field as optional (required=False) and implement a custom validation to ensure the field has content:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    myfield = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(empty_label=(u'year', u'month', u'day')),
                              required=False)

    def clean_myfield(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['myfield']
        if not value:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please fill out myfield')
        return value
```