# django setting initial value on form for DateTimeField to '--------'

Tags: python, django, forms, python-datetime

I want the expire date to remain required, so I don't want to use Required=False.  However, I want it to initially show as '-------' for each of the three dropdowns (month, day, year) instead of January 1 2017 for the dropdowns.

```
from django import forms 

class LicenseCreateForm(forms.ModelForm): 
     expire= forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(),)
```

---

Comment: When you create an object it doesn't show '-------'? It's the default django behaviour on create.

Comment: no, I have gotten the default '------' before where other types. I am wondering if the datetime field doesn't default to the dashes

Comment: The dashes will only be displayed if the field is not required. Is your field optional?

Comment: That is the issue I am having,  It has to be required.  But I need a way to make sure the user doesn't accidentally submit with the default date.  That is why I prefer it to show the dashes first.  As it stands, if the user presses submit, it takes the default date.

Comment: In that case see [Display empty\_label on required selectDateWidget on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378379/display-empty-label-on-required-selectdatewidget-on-django)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing doing it with jquery.

```
$("#id_expire_month").prepend("<option value='---' selected='selected'></option>");
$("#id_expire_day").prepend("<option value='---' selected='selected'></option>");
$("#id_expire_year").prepend("<option value='---' selected='selected'></option>");
```