# Empty choice with SelectDateWidget in django 1.11

Tags: python, django

For the SelectDateWidget, Django documentation states the following:

> If the DateField is not required, SelectDateWidget will have an empty
>   choice at the top of the list (which is --- by default). You can
>   change the text of this label with the empty_label attribute.
>   empty_label can be a string, list, or tuple. When a string is used,
>   all select boxes will each have an empty choice with this label. If
>   empty_label is a list or tuple of 3 string elements, the select boxes
>   will have their own custom label. The labels should be in this order
>   ('year_label', 'month_label', 'day_label').

However, it is not clear to me how to set empty choice with the required date field? I assume this is not a rare situation: without the empty choices, but with default values preselected, one can easily skip the required date field and save it with the default values without noticing.

Does someone knows how to do this?

Comment: Yes this is so basic yet there is no readily available solution that i could find. were you able to find a solution

Comment: Not really. At the moment, I do in models.py date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True) and in forms.py self.fields['date'].required = True. That way I get the desired behaviour in the custom form user uses. But if you want to edit the object in django admin, it will not mark the date field required and will not complain you need to enter a value at the level of the form, but once you click Save, you will get the "null value in column "date" violates not-null constraint". So this is obviously not the correct way to do it, but I know no other way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display empty\_label on required selectDateWidget on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378379/display-empty-label-on-required-selectdatewidget-on-django)

Comment: The accepted answer in the post linked by Julian Go no longer works in more recent Django versions, but I just added an answer that should work for those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by subclassing SelectDateWidget and overriding get_context.

```
class MySelectDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        old_state = self.is_required
        self.is_required = False
        context = super(MySelectDateWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        self.is_required = old_state
        return context
```

This answer is similar to GwynBleidD's from the thread here: [Display empty_label on required selectDateWidget on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378379/display-empty-label-on-required-selectdatewidget-on-django/56812567?noredirect=1#comment100187081_56812567), but updated to work with more recent versions of Django.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately looking at the code of SelectDateWidget there is no nice way to do this(django 2.1.4).
My solution was to add the empty choices client-side(using jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select-widget-id select').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).children('[value=""], [selected]').length) {
      $(this).prepend('<option value="" selected="selected">---</option>');
    }
  });
});
```